# Android Marking an application installed

Tags: android, installation

I have a question for you: i have an application where some apks could be downloaded and installed. 
I launch installation in this way:

> Intent myIntent = new Intent();
>                   myIntent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
>                   myIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + getFilesDir() + "/" + m_sLastFileName ), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
>                   startActivity(myIntent);

Now i have this problem: i want to know which apks the user has installed, so the question is: can i mark the installed applications in a way that i can recognise them as "My App"?
Or can you suggest me an alternative solution?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is an example of this in the API demos in the SDK.
In particular the following code looks through programs trying to recognise its "own"

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/ApiDemos.html

Comment: Thanks. This is a useful example but i need something different. This code is searching for activities that have a specific category inside the manifest. I can't modify the manifest of existing apks

Comment: I thought you could remove the category qualification and use the prefix bit to pick out your apps, or just compare with a list.